# Cannot set the app as profile owner - set-profile-owner command stuck

Tags: android, android-source, mdm, device-policy-manager, dpm

I'm trying to set the profile owner for one of my application using command on my Android 10 device:

adb shell dpm set-profile-owner com.example.blockcamera/.BlockCameraDeviceAdminReceiver

When I press Enter nothing happens - the command will be stuck with a cursor flashing on new line. I have to Ctrl+C to kill it.

The command works fine on Android Emulator and the app works as expected afterwords.
I am using android:testOnly flag in AndroidManifest.xml

Things tried:

1. Used --user current option but no luck
2. Also tried set-device-owner command but same result, the command gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I reset the device and it worked later.